# Filler elements added to a Java array

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Why does Java add trailing filler elements to an array if the array is purposely populated with less than the declared size? See code for an example.

```
package fillerelements;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FillerElements {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // declare a one-dimensional array, size 25
    int arrlist[] = new int[25];

    // print length of arrlist
    System.out.println("length of arrlist is " + arrlist.length);

    // populate arrlist with 10 elements even though its declared size is 25
    // compiler will add 15 trailing 0s
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      arrlist[i] = i + 1;

    // print arrlist
    System.out.print("arrlist: ");
    for(int j = 0; j < arrlist.length; j++)
      System.out.print(arrlist[j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    // partial output from above
    /* arrlist: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 */

    // print arrlist as an array
    System.out.println("length of arrlist is " + arrlist.length);
    System.out.println("arrlist: " + Arrays.toString(arrlist));

    // partial output from above
    /* arrlist: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] */
  }
}
```

Comment: Java arrays have a fixed length. You seem to expect the behavior of an `ArrayList`, just use that if that is what you want. To be clear: when you say `int arrlist[] = new int[25];` you get an array of **twenty-five** zeros.

Comment: What else should they do instead of filling it with zeros? It actually fills it with zeros at the line `int arrlist[] = new int[25];`

Comment: @Tyler --- so its nature is to be filled at the time of declaration and all I'm doing is over writing those values?

Comment: @MichaelSwartz Yes that is correct. I agree with Elliott, you can use ArrayList for a more dynamic approach, and can add elements to the end as needed, if this is not the functionality you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java arrays have a fixed length and are always initialized to well-defined values for the type of array. For `int[]` this is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a variable and don't initializate it directly, it takes a default value which is `0` for `int`, so for an `int[]` it will give `{0,0,...,0}`

```
int arrlist[] = new int[25]; //-> {0,0,...,0}
```

Then you erase and replace some values, but not all

---

Details here : [Java Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#h1)

Answer (score 0):

You probably can create a ArrayList. See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/

`List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

See your modified example

```
    int arrlist[] = new int[25];
    List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // print length of arrlist
    System.out.println("length of arrlist is " + arrlist.length);
    System.out.println("length of arrayList is " + arrayList.size());

    // populate arrlist with 10 elements even though its declared size is 25
    // compiler will add 15 trailing 0s
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arrlist[i] = i + 1;
        arrayList.add(i + 1);
    }

    // print arrlist
    System.out.print("arrlist: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < arrlist.length; j++)
        System.out.print(arrlist[j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    // print arrlist
    System.out.print("arrayList: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++)
        System.out.print(arrayList.get(j) + " ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
```

//Output

`length of arrlist is 25`

`length of arrayList is 0`

`arrlist: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

`arraylist: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`